# Drop down menu over frames?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have 2 iframes on my page. One is a menu pane (frame1), the other the content pane. The menu frame height is 100 and remaining for content frame , I can't change the height of the frame1 for various reasons. I used CSS drop down menu in the menu frame, when I use menu frame height is 200 or 300 the drop down is showing properly but small height it unable to show.

What I need to do to show the main menu in frame1 and dropdown submenu in frame2? Heard it is called as cross frame drop down menu. Please let me know how I can resolve my problem.
I'm okay with HTML, CSS, JavaScript and PHP. Hope I can resolve this in this four languages.

Comment: So each top menu click loads a page in the frame below with a differnet drop dowbn? Not sure I understand whioch is why I deleted my original answer

Comment: I have only one drop down menu , Dat is working fine if am using it in one frame but my webpage has 3 frames So the Drop down is not coming because of the height of the frame ... That is the issue .. How i can resolve it ?? Pls help.

Answer (score 1):

I think not using frames is you're best answer. Websites are usualy more acessible and user friendly if you design them how they were meant to be designed rather than hacking things.

Comment: Intelligent answer ... but its not the solution @DavidB

Comment: I wasnt sure what the question was to be honest, see my comment on your questions above

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `$("#iframe_id").contents().find('#some_element')` to access elements in the second iframe from the parent element and you can access parent js functions from frame1 with `parent.yourFunction()`.
Smth. like this:
In frame1:
`<div class='menu_btn' onclick='parent.openMenu();'></div>`
In parent:

```
function openMenu() {  
$("#iframe2").contents().find('#some_element').show();
}
```

**Though the solution is rather weird.

I suggest you to consider changing all the page view, getting rid of frames.**